# Many to Many association in Grails 4

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

I'm working on a new project using Grails 4.0.1. In this project I have two domain classes, the first is `Person` and the second is `Document`. Between these classes there is a many-to-many association. However, I also need to store the order (position) of each Person in each Document. Is there any way to model this kind of behavior in Grails 4?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `Document.persons` as `List`:

```
class Document {
  List<Person> persons
  static hasMany = [ persons:Person ]
}

class Person {
  static hasMany = [ documents:Document ]
}
```

see [ref-doc](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#sets) for further info

Comment: I don't think that will work.  I think when you have `hasMany` at both ends that one end must have `belongsTo`.  Am I mistaken about that?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm not a fan of many-to-many relations at all, but I still think that  the `person_idx` column will be created in the join table automatically

Comment: Ok.  In earlier versions of GORM we would throw an error at session factory initialization time if you used the approach you described here.  Maybe that has changed recently and I overlooked it.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: FYI... It looks like https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/89aade5cd642f7646ab0dcf11130b3be88eefd21#diff-15bc6afdb935dd08b43d65654656127aL506 is where the `"No owner defined between domain classes [class manytomany.SomeClass] and [class manytomany.SomeOtherClass] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = manytomany.SomeOtherClass"` exception was removed.

Comment: @injecteer Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work for me. I still need to model the position of the persons (authors) in each document. So, the third table (automatically generated with your code example), should have the order or position attribute. Is there any way to do that in Grails 4.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours, I got the solution more suitable for my use case. This is the solution:

1. We create two base classes: `Person` and `Document`:

   ```
   class Person {

   String name

   static hasMany = [documentPerson: DocumentPerson]

   static constraints = {
       name blank: false, nullable: false, maxSize: 255
       documentPerson nullable: true
     }
   }

   class Document {

   String title

   static hasMany = [documentPerson: DocumentPerson]

   static mapping = {
       tablePerHierarchy false
   }

   static constraints = {
       title blank: false, maxSize: 255, nullable: true
       documentPerson nullable: true
    }
   }
   ```

Next, we define the class `DocumentPerson`:

```
    class DocumentPerson {

    Integer position
    Person person
    Document document

    static constraints = {
        position nullable: false
        document nullable: false
        person nullable: false
     }
   }
```

At this point, we have three tables in the database as expected.

Comment: you can do it this way, especially if you need other attributes in your `DocumentPerson` class. On the downside is that you have to fill the `position` property yourself, whereas in a default solution (depicted by me) the framework takes care of it